# Is it OK that entire table can relate only to certain items in a table?

Tags: database

Assume that I have a table of toys with properties like amusability, price, breakage rate, date bought, place where bought. (Some rc cars, brain teasers, planes, some LEGO sets). But then I'm interested in pieces LEGO sets have. Is it perfectly OK, that I create another table "pieces of set" with keys(indices) to toys in the "toy" tables, but these keys will actually point only to toys with pointer to category ("category" is also table) "LEGO Sets"? So that an entire table "pieces of set" actually relates only to certain items in a table "toy"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Now, answers on SO need to be longer than one word, so here are some Wikipedia articles you may want to have a go with:
"[Cardinality (data modeling)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_(data_modeling))" and "[Entity-attribute-value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)"